# Search for Pattern with blank line UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have to find the .sql files on my UNIX box which has a blank line between two specific line pattern.

For ex:

The below code is fine.

```
CREATE VIEW V_NAME_LAST
AS
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE
```

The Below code is NOT fine as we have space b/w AS and SELECT.

```
CREATE VIEW V_NAME_LAST
AS

SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE
```

Can you please let me know a simple grep pattern search to find such files?

Also, a hint that we will have files with blank lines which are fine, i need only b/w AS  SELECT

Answer (score 0):

```
^ *$
```

Since you are only interested in the names of these files, you should use the `-l` option of grep.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a little Perl script, as follows:

```
perl -0777 -wne '/(\bAS\n\nSELECT\b)/ and print "$ARGV\n"' file1 file2 ...
```

The `-0777` turns on `file mode` so the entire file is read and treated as a single record. The `-w` emits warnings for any bad things my code does. The `-n` wraps the following code in a `while` loop. And `-e` means that the program to execute follows next.

The program says... *"if you find the word "AS" followed by two newlines then the word "SELECT", print the name of the file you are looking in"*.

So, you could use it with `find` like this:

```
find ~ -name \*.sql -exec perl -0777 -wne '/(\bAS\n\nSELECT\b)/ and print "$ARGV\n"' {} \;
```

If your `find` supports it, replace the final `\;` with `+` and it will run faster.